# Calling overridden child method from base method in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
class A 
{
public:
  void foo()
  {
    cout<<"this is base foo()"<<endl;
  }

  void callfoo()
  {
    foo();
  }
};

class B: public A
{
public:
  void foo()
  {
    cout<<"this is child foo()"<<endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  B b;
  b.callfoo(); //Output: "this is base foo()"
  b.foo();     //Output: "this is child foo()"
  return 0;
}
```

Now when I call `b.callfoo()`, instead of calling the `foo()` of child class B, `callfoo()` calls `foo()` of base class A. In class B we have overridden `foo()` with a new implementation, but still `callfoo()` is calling the base `foo()` instead of the child `foo()`. Please help if you have any explanation for this behaviour.

Comment: When you post code here, you should make sure the code is indented in a reasonable fashion to make it more readable, and use the back-tick to format "inline" code references.

Comment: The code is also full of typos.

Comment: Sorry guys, I am new here didn't knew the format to ask questions. Also I apologise for typos. Regards...

Answer (score 3):

In C++, you need to explicitly mark methods as overridable by adding the `virtual` keyword: `virtual void foo()`.

Comment: But when I call `foo()`; from Base class object b, without using virtual keyword in `foo()`, overriding happens and child `foo()` is called. So virtual function is only helpful when we are calling child class overridden method from base class method?(Apart from using a base pointer to call child methods)

Comment: Correct - but calling a virtual method through a base pointer or reference (which is essentially what's happening when you're calling it from a base class method too) and having the derived class' override method run is called _polymorphism_, and it's a very powerful concept.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset and what if I need to override a non-virtual method of a parent class I can't modify ? Is that not possible at all ?

Comment: @TheEagle: No. If the parent class is well-designed, the method being non-virtual means that there are good reasons you shouldn't be overriding it. If it is not, you're probably out of luck - unless you control all the places where instances of that class are being used. Then, you could introduce a wrapper class with virtual functions that call the real functions, and make all call sites go through that wrapper class. Then you can extend the wrapper instead and override the function.